# Movement visualizer (travel time calculator) issues

Tags: python, python-3.x, math, calculator

```
import time
import os

clear = lambda: os.system('cls')
clear()

print('Movement Computer')
print('')
distance = float(input('Distance (km): '))
currVelocity = float(input('Velocity (km/h): '))
acceleration = float(input('Acceleration (km/h^2): '))
timeLeap = float(input('Time leap (h): '))

path = ''
gap = ''
travel = ''
travelled = 0
multiplier = 1
loop = 0

for x in range(0, 100):
    path = path + '='

for y in range(0, 50):
    gap = gap + ' '

eachCube = distance / 100

while True:
    clear()
    print('eachCube: ' + str(eachCube))
    print ('Travelled / eachCube: ' + str(travelled / eachCube))
    print ('eachCube * multiplier: ' + str(eachCube * multiplier))
    print ('multiplier: ' + str(multiplier))
    print('')
    print(gap + ' Space')
    print(' ' + path)
    print(travel + '^')
    print('')
    print('Current velocity  : ' + str(currVelocity))
    print('Distance traveled : ' + str(travelled) + '/' + str(distance))
    print('Time: ' + str(loop))
    if travelled >= distance:
        print('')
        print('Journey complete.')
        break
    time.sleep(timeLeap)
    loop += 1
    currVelocity += acceleration * timeLeap
    travelled += currVelocity * timeLeap
    if travelled >= eachCube * multiplier:
        for z in range(0, int(int(travelled / eachCube) / loop)):
            travel = travel + ' '
        multiplier = loop
```

I've been killing some time making this object movement visualizer.. Everything works ok when Acceleration is set 0 but when I change it the arrow (pointer) gets all messed up.

Could someone help me? Also I do know that the arrow can go off the chart (couldn't fix that either)

There's probably something wrong with the code that makes the pointer (arrow) move:

```
if travelled >= eachCube * multiplier:
    for z in range(0, int(int(travelled / eachCube) / loop)):
        travel = travel + ' '
    multiplier = loop
```

where `eachCube = distance / 100` and `travelled` is the distance the object has already moved.

Comment: Your question is not at all clear, and when I run your code I have no idea what is happening or what is supposed to happen. Please explain more just what you want to happen from your cod, what actually happens, and what the differences are.

Comment: In the program you choose certain arguments, which it uses to simulate the movement of an object (on a certain line) and calculates how much time it takes to move from point A to point B with those arguments.

Comment: My problem is that changing acceleration to anything from 0 bugs the program. I dont know how to fix that

Comment: 1) What means "bugs the program"? It calculated something with acceleration > 0 in my interpreter.

Comment: 2) Please don't hide additional information in comments - people tend just to read the question. You can edit it. 3) Wouldn't a graph with `matplotlib` or `seaborn` give the information in a more interesting way? Reading blocks of information is somewhat hard to interpret.

Comment: @Piinthesky The arrow is supposed to stay on the line (it's supposed to always point on the line) sometimes it happens that in the end of the calculation the arrow doesnt even get to the end or that in overshoots somewhere after the end point.

Comment: Ah. I only now noticed the function of this arrow. Then you have to implement `if arrowposition > length of line: arrowposition = length of line` and terminate the loop. I assume they are represented in your code by `path` and `travel`.

Comment: @Piinthesky yes thx, that's when it overshoots the line, but when it stays somewhere in the middle at the end of the calculation, I can't change travel to path because it would teleport the arrow too drastically.

Comment: The problems seem to occur when changing acceleration from 0 or when changing timeLeap from 1, I was thinking something might be wrong with the code on the last 4 lines.. Normally I would probably solve this at some point but sometimes my brain just stops working with code completely so I can't do anything at all.. :D

Comment: FIY timeLeap is used for how often the arrow should update..

Comment: Maybe you should update your question with an example input where this undesired behaviour occurs. I don't know, what to look for.